# Can't write at Java Console when NPE/EJB exception arises

Tags: java, stateless

Why I can't write at console when some checked exception arises in my class annotated with "@Stateless"?

```
        try {
            boolean flagUnidadeSemEmail = StringUtils.isBlank(n.getUnidade().getEmail());
            String destinatario = !flagUnidadeSemEmail ? n.getUnidade().getEmail() : n.getProcessoJudicial().getEmailJuizRequisitante();
            destinatario = null;
            UtilEmail.getInstance().enviaEmail(destinatario, txt, templateEmail.getTituloEmail());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Falha no envio email: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: How looks the error message you recieved?

Comment: Maybe `e.getCause()` is `null`? That would cause another exception to be thrown (and maybe caught elsewhere)

Comment: Just don't write.